# SQL Server : Getting distinct count on every column in a large view

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large SQL Server 2012 database with a couple of views I need to analyse.

What I want to know for each view is the number of unique values of each column in the view. I could not find any script yet that would give me this.

So the input should be the view name and the output would be two rows like:

```
Column         Uniques
accountid      200
accountname    178
numberofemp     23
telephone      154
notusedyet       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `COUNT()` (*an aggregate function*) with *Distinct* to count only the unique values.

```
SELECT  [column], COUNT(DISTINCT value) [Uniques]
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY [column]
```

Answer (score 2):

Get a distinct count for each column via `count(distinct [ColA])` for each column you want to count (no `group by`).  You can then unpivot to get the tabular format you desire.  Here's an example:

```
;with DistinctColumnCount( Id, Description )
as
(
    select
        count(distinct Id) Id
        , count(distinct Description) Description
    from
        EntityB
)

SELECT CountColumn, [Count].[DistinctCount]
FROM 
    DistinctColumnCount
unpivot
    ( DistinctCount for CountColumn in ( Id, [Description] ) ) as [Count]
```

Comment: Hi Moho, Thanks for your script. I think I get the picture now. Could it be that some more script on top fell off? How do you build the DistinctColumnCount table?

Comment: DistinctColumnCount is a common table expressions (CTE) - it's a reusable 'subquery'.  You can replace its implementation in the `FROM` clause of the select statement, if you wish

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx